# How can I test the PPM of different minerals in my Water?

Tags: water

As a follow up question to [this](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/how-do-water-filters-effect-the-minerals-in-water), I'm interesting in testing every batch of tap water for the PPM of various minerals (calcium, magnesium, sodium, chloride, sulfate, etc). Are these test strips available at the LHBS? I saw that Northern Brewer had complete water testing kits available starting at $100, but I would rather not pay that much.

How can I test the PPM of the tap water, myself?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to test every batch of water?  In most cases, other than chlorine/chloramine, it will be pretty stable.  Are you on a well or city supply?  I have my well water tested every 3-5 years and it hardly changes at all.  Not enough to be concerned about.

Comment: $25 http://www.ternwater.com/know-your-water/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're insistent on testing it yourself, aquarium supply places purportedly have testing kits, but I haven't looked into them.

[You can also send a (pre- or post-filtered) sample to Ward Labs, who have multiple specific homebrewer water tests](https://producers.wardlab.com/BrewersKitOrder.aspx) for $30-40. As Denny mentions, doing this on a multi-year period (or if you feel/know that things are changing due to municipal water changes) is totally sufficient. Also, the municipal water organization will likely have a yearly report, though if it's like most it'll have most but not all of the ion values you care about as a homebrewer.

Comment: Awesome. I am going to send a pre- and post-filtered sample to Ward Labs.

Comment: $25 http://www.ternwater.com/know-your-water/